# Pointers to cloud service which supports JBoss, Apache and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache, jboss, cloud-hosting

Hi I need some recommendations/ pointers for some cloud services which support jboss,apache and mysql. I will also need to install php module. I am working on an application which uses PHP, Java (Java EE) and mysql in backend.

I know I can potentially do that on Amazon EC2, but was looking for cheaper options. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Openshift?

Openshift promises open choice which means you can deploy Java, PHP, Ruby applications  to it. Its supported platforms seems to be growing constantly. They recently added support for MongoDB as well.

```
openshift.redhat.com
```

Openshift is free as in free beer.

Some useful references

```
[1] http://www.schabell.org/p/free-linux-courses.html
[2] https://openshift.redhat.com/app/getting_started
[3] https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/videos
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out Cloudify - http://www.cloudifysource.org

It's an open-source Platform as a Service, and supports multiple cloud vendors, including EC2, Azure, Openstack (including HP and Rackspace)